# Plugin overwrites Wordpress Page Permalinks

Tags: wordpress

I've created a plugin that registers a custom taxonomy which can be used in the permalink structure. It's an issue management plugin. When it's active, all the posts can be displayed fine but pages all return a 404. I have the permalink set to /%issue%/%category%/%postname%/.
Again this works fine for posts but breaks pages. Here is the code:

I've reset the permalink multiple times and deletes .htaccess but nothing works. Could anyone offer suggestions of what hooks or functions might be breaking permalinks for pages?

Comment: Why not make a custom post type called "Issues" and create a post when an issue is raised with the page name? Either way can we have some code to see?

Comment: The entire plugin can be found here. https://github.com/lingz/issuer

Comment: Also sorry, but I don't quite understand your recommendation. Could you please clarify?